# How do I build a left derivation tree from an expression including right-to-left associativity?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

Suppose I want to make a left derivation tree of an expression, but the expression includes operators that are right-to-left associative. Would I still expand the left-most variable first in my tree? For example, the expression `a + b ** c ** d` where `**` is right-to-left associative, and `+` is left-to-right associative.

Answer (score 1):

In a leftmost derivation, you always expand the leftmost non-terminal, by definition. The question is, what do you expand it to, since you usually have more than one choice.

Comment: What is a situation where you would have more than one choice? Not sure I really understand what you're saying there.

Comment: @jimtimbim: If you take a look at expression grammars, you'll see that most non-terminals have more than one possible production. If that still doesn't make sense, try doing some derivations on paper.